# If(isset()) with select options

Tags: php, html

I was wondering why my code is not working.
Here is my html:

```
<select class="form-control" name="trademarktm">            
    <option name='empty'></option>
    <option name='copyright'>©</option>
    <option name='trademark'>™</option>
    <option name='rmark'>®</option>
</select>
```

i gave the copyright token the name 'copyright' so i could call it in my PHP like i did here:

```
if(isset($_POST['copyright'])) {
echo "<div id='generated_footer_date' style='background-color:$backgroundColor; color:$fontColor; opacity: $opacity; ' >$trademark $date $company </div>";          
} else {
echo "error";
}
```

In this case i only get the string Error even if copyright is set.

Comment: try `$_POST['trademark'] === "copyright"`

Comment: if($_POST['trademark']=== "copyright") { }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `select` gets the `name`, not the `option`. The `option` should have the `value`.

```
<select class="form-control" name="trademarktm">            
    <option value='empty'></option>
    <option value='copyright'>©</option>
    <option value='trademark'>™</option>
    <option value='rmark'>®</option>
</select>
```

Then...

```
if(isset($_POST['trademarktm']) && $_POST['trademarktm'] == 'copyright') {
     echo "<div id='generated_footer_date' style='background-color:$backgroundColor; color:$fontColor; opacity: $opacity; ' >$trademark $date $company </div>";          
} else {
     echo "error";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control" name="trademarktm">            
<option value='empty'></option>
<option value='copyright'>©</option>
<option value='trademark'>™</option>
<option value='rmark'>®</option>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['trademarktm']) && $_POST['trademark']=== "copyright") { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change This:

```
if(isset($_POST['copyright']))
```

TO

```
if(isset($_POST['trademarktm']) && $_POST['trademarktm'] === 'copyright')
```

Comment: but how do i know when the copyright option is selected

Comment: i want to run a script when people select the copyright option

Comment: it will pass one of the selected value in post array

Comment: The OP needs to update the HTML for this to work as well, as is none of the `option`s have `value`s.

Answer (score 1):

try to this..

```
if($_POST['trademarktm'] == 'copyright') {
echo "<div id='generated_footer_date' style='background-color:$backgroundColor; color:$fontColor; opacity: $opacity; ' >$trademark $date $company </div>";          
} else {
echo "error";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have any empty options. So if you don't choose another option then the first one will be used.

The first option should be something like this:

```
<option value='nogood'></option>
```

then use if/else for checking the value:

```
if ($_POST['trademarktm'] == 'nogood') {
    echo 'error'; 
}
else {
    echo "<div id='generated_footer_date' style='background-color:$backgroundColor; color:$fontColor; opacity: $opacity; ' >$trademark $date $company </div>";
}
```